# Adding an alias for Sublime Text to zshrc

Tags: alias, zsh, sublimetext2, zshrc

Just have a quick question on how to add an alias for SublimeText to my ZSH. I've been to their site where they tell you how to do it within bash, but I don't understand how to do it within ZSH. It has been killing me, I just want to open text files from my command prompt. Anyone out there have experience with ZSH where they have created aliases?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Aliases in `zsh` are created in the same manner as in `bash`.

```
alias somealias='something longer'
```

Now  somealias will expand to 'something longer' (without the quotes). Put it into `~/.zshrc` to make it persistent.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated. Placed them in my ~/.zshrc

Comment: To be more specific, `alias subl="'/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl'"`

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example how to add `subl` command for ZSH

http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/05/11/sublime-text-2-tips-for-python-and-web-developers/#Open_files_from_comma

Here is another example how to make UNIX EDITOR env var to use Sublime and behave well e.g. when editing subversion and git commit messages

https://github.com/miohtama/ztanesh/blob/master/zsh-scripts/rc/39-osx-vars#L11

https://github.com/miohtama/ztanesh/blob/master/zsh-scripts/bin/subl-wrapper

Answer (score 0):

Just make an alias in `~/zshrc`

Add this:

`alias subl="'/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl'"`

Then when you are in the right folder, you can always type `subl .` to open that folder with Sublime