# aliasing sudo with zshrc - gets "aliased to nocorrect sudo"

Tags: linux, shell, zshrc

I've checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12334681/adding-an-alias-for-sublime-text-to-zshrc) answer first:

My question still is:

If I put these lines to my ~.zshrc file :

```
JAVA_HOME="/user/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64"
export JAVA_HOME

alias sudo="sudo env JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME"
```

Then do logout.

Then try :

```
> sudo ./somejava-stuff.sh
```

I still see "The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined"

When I check whether my alias was applied:

```
> which sudo
```

I got unexpected output that says:

> "sudo: aliased to nocorrect sudo"

**Q:** Why it is so?

If I do this manually:

```
> sudo env JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME ./somejava-stuff.sh
```

It works fine.

--
Also I tried to set "alias with the space" as was suggested [here](https://superuser.com/questions/605417/how-do-i-use-sudo-with-alias-in-zsh)

I tired also this:

```
...

alias sudo='nocorrect sudo'
alias sudo="sudo env JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME "
```

Like was suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37709/how-to-disable-autocorrection-for-sudo-command-in-zsh).

Comment: Ok.. I guess this "just not working": https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto/issues/531

Answer (score 1):

> Q: Why it is so?

This is because your init files override your custom `sudo` alias. You can only have one alias for one command at a time.

What you can do:

#### Method 1

Choose another name for your alias:

```
alias jsudo='sudo env JAVA_HOME="$JAVA_HOME"'
```

Also note the difference in quoting between your version and this.

#### Method 2

Find and delete the line in your zsh init files that is overriding your alias. Somewhere, there will be a line saying `alias sudo='nocorrect sudo'`.

If you are unable to find this line, you have to stick with **Method 1**. This would be a failure on your part, and not a problem with zsh or Linux.

Update your `sudo` alias with

```
alias sudo='nocorrect sudo env JAVA_HOME="$JAVA_HOME"'
```

---

PS: The whole `nocorrect` business is to prevent zsh from correcting your command, which is typically not helpful for sudo.